# Why is yelded object '#<Object>' read-only?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator, yield

I have a simple search I've implemented using yield - run through a recursive folder structure, yield all folders.  My implementation is fairly simple, and I've removed all "const" (just in case)

```
function *folders(f: Folder) : IterableIterator<Folder> {
    yield f;
    if (f.folders)
    {
        for (let sf of f.folders) {
            yield* folders(sf);
        }    
    }
}

function *allFolders() : IterableIterator<Folder> {
    for (let p of projects) {
        yield* folders(p.project.rootFolder!)
    }
}
```

When I try to modify the returned object

```
let folders = allFolders();
let t = folders.next().value;
t.name = "sdvs";
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<Object>'
```

If I access the object directly (it's sitting at global scope in this file) it's fine.  I've spent several hours on this now, and am completely perplexed.  Is this simply not possible?  Why might this be happening?

Comment: Please show us how you defined `projects`, and how the `Folder` type is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - my problem was that I was using immer in my reducer (somewhere way back up the tree), at some point this instance was shallow-cloned and passed to my reducer (it's data for a fake DB).

Fixed by doing a deepclone before returning any data from my fake DB.